# foreign key referencing to two tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a set of three tables (`runStats`, `failedRuns` and `readsInfo`), as shown below (I am creating the database and tables using the sqalchemy module in Python):

```
#### Create the runstats table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS runStats (
            runStats_ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            samplesheet_name varchar(100),
            run_ID varchar(100),
            minimal_cluster_density varchar(100),
            percentage_clusters_post_filter FLOAT,
            percentage_reads_w_quality_greater_than_Q30 FLOAT,
            percentage_aligned_phiX_reads FLOAT,
            error_rate FLOAT,
            UNIQUE (runStats_ID, samplesheet_name, run_ID, minimal_cluster_density, percentage_clusters_post_filter, percentage_reads_w_quality_greater_than_Q30, percentage_aligned_phiX_reads, error_rate),
            PRIMARY KEY (runStats_ID)
            )''')
#### add the column run_ID as unique index, so that it can be used as a foreign key in the table readsInfo
c.execute("""ALTER TABLE runStats ADD UNIQUE INDEX run_ID_UNIQUE (run_ID)""")


#### create the table failedRuns
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS failedRuns (
        fail_ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        run_ID varchar(100),
        reason_fail varchar(100),
        PRIMARY KEY (fail_ID),
        UNIQUE(fail_ID, run_ID, reason_fail)
        )""")
#### add the unique index on the column run_ID, as this should also be referenced as a foreign key
c.execute("""ALTER TABLE failedRuns ADD UNIQUE INDEX run_ID_UNIQUE (run_ID)""")


#### Create the readsInfo table
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS readsInfo (
        readsInfo_ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        run_ID varchar(100),
        total_number_of_reads BIGINT,
        total_number_of_reads_post_filter BIGINT,
        percentage_reads_identified_post_filter FLOAT,
        cv FLOAT,
        min FLOAT,
        max FLOAT,
        UNIQUE(readsInfo_ID, total_number_of_reads, total_number_of_reads_post_filter, percentage_reads_identified_post_filter, cv, min, max, run_ID),
        PRIMARY KEY (readsInfo_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (run_ID) REFERENCES runStats(run_ID)
        )""")
```

In the code above, I have a FK on the `run_ID` field on table `readsInfo`, which references to the field `run_ID` in the table `runStats`. The thing is that, in this column I should accept values that are present not only in the `run_ID` field in table `runStats`, but also in the `run_ID` field in the table `failedRuns` (considering a collection of `run_IDs`, they will go to the field `run_ID` in the table `runStats` **or** in the table `failedRuns`).

Long story short, the field `run_ID` in the table `readsInfo` should reference to the field `run_ID` in table `readsInfo` **or** `failedRuns`.

Comment: A foreign key cannot reference 2 tables. Have you considered a trigger?

Comment: Er, never heard of it (I am quite new to DBMS). How can triggers help me in this example, would you kindly have a word on that?

Comment: From my PoV, you should implement your `or` logic in your Python code - triggers are also an option but I found them more complex in sense of testing / maintaining. I would also recommend installing MySQL Workbench for working with DB only.